# Can't add this piece of jQuery code in the sample

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a bit of trouble adding the following piece of jQuery code in the code. It basically adds dots to words. I tried the following jQuery and when added into the click function it doesn't work. But yet outside of the click function it works.

How do I add it in so that only once the button is clicked, will step 1 appear with the dots following. After 10 seconds make it move to step 2 doing the same things again like step 1. Until I reach step 5 which will show completed and stop flashing?

```
var dots = 0;
setInterval (type, 1000);

function type()
{
    if(dots < 5)
    {
        $('#dots').append('.');
        dots++;
    }
    else
    {
        $('#dots').html('');
        dots = 0;
    }
}
```

This is what I've managed so far:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // all jQuery code goes here  

  $("a").click(function() {
    // do something here  
    // when any anchor is clicked 

    $("#flash").html("STEP1"); // content inside #myElement will be replaced with that specified  

    var flash = $('#flash');

    function runIt() {
      flash.animate({
        opacity: '+=1'
      }, 400);
      flash.animate({
        opacity: '+=1'
      }, 200);
      flash.animate({
        opacity: '-=0.9'
      }, 600, runIt);
    }
    runIt();
  });
  
});
```

```css
.test {
  float: left;
}

#flash {
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  color: red;
}

.classname {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fceaca;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fceaca;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fceaca;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffce79), color-stop(1, #eeaf41));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffce79 5%, #eeaf41 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffce79', endColorstr='#eeaf41');
  background-color: #ffce79;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  text-indent: 0;
  border: 1px solid #eeb44f;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ce8e28;
}

.classname:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #eeaf41), color-stop(1, #ffce79));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #eeaf41 5%, #ffce79 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eeaf41', endColorstr='#ffce79');
  background-color: #eeaf41;
}

.classname:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"><a href="#" id="text" class="classname">TEXT</a></div>

<div class="test">
  <div id="flash">Start<span id="dots"></span></div>
</div>
```

It's basically suppose to like a progress bar with 5 different status, start and finish do not flash, steps in between start and finish flash to show progress

Comment: You should do this bit `setInterval(type, 1000);` within the `click` event you want. http://jsfiddle.net/9ETDg/1/

Comment: But then, the `.html("STEP1")` call removes the `#dots` element...

Comment: sorry my explanation wasn't good. I updated the link and I want it exactly like that. Only difference is I want the dots to be added when STEP 1 appears and starts flashing

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
var dots = 0;
var step = 1;
var flag = false;

var $all = $('#all');
var $flash = $('#flash');
var $dots = $('#dots');

function type()
{
    if(dots < 5)
    {
        $dots.append('.');
        dots++;
        setTimeout(type, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        $flash.html('Completed');
        $dots.html('');
        flag = true;
        dots = 0;
    }
}

function start() {

    $flash.html("STEP"+step);
    step++;

    function runIt() {
        $all.animate({opacity:'+=1'}, 400);
        $all.animate({opacity:'+=1'}, 200);

        if (flag){ 
            return flag = false;
        }
        $all.animate({opacity:'-=0.9'}, 600, runIt);
    }
    runIt();
    type();
}

$('#text').on('click', start);
```

I also made some changes in HTML and CSS. Everything is in the demo:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ETDg/6/)**

Comment: Close but the other way around. The time delay and dots apply to the STEP 1 not to the START

Comment: I needed to completely restructure your code. See my edited answer.

Comment: ok so looking at your code the only two things I noticed was that "setTimeout(type, 1000);" I put for the speed of dots, on yours it moves to completed straight after it. How would you add a time delay before completed appears? So the dots go to 5 and restart counting from one dot to 5 until time delay is met